# What packages are installed on a fresh installation?

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu

Which packages are installed on a clean Kubuntu 11.04 Natty desktop installation?

The list of installed packages can be retrieved by running:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | awk '{print "    "$2}'
```

(the result is prefixed with four spaces for proper code formatting on Askubuntu)

This should be done on a **clean** installation. Live CDs are not suitable for this job because these include additional packages for the installation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packlist below for a freshly install 11.04 kubuntu installation into a virtualbox guest:

```
acpi-support
acpid
adduser
akonadi-server
akregator
alsa-base
alsa-utils
amarok
amarok-common
amarok-utils
anacron
app-install-data
apparmor
apparmor-utils
appmenu-gtk
appmenu-qt
apport
apport-kde
apport-symptoms
apt
apt-transport-https
apt-utils
apt-xapian-index
apturl-common
apturl-kde
ark
aspell
aspell-en
at
avahi-autoipd
avahi-daemon
avahi-utils
base-files
base-passwd
bash
bash-completion
bc
bind9-host
binutils
bluedevil
bluez
bluez-alsa
bluez-cups
brltty
bsdmainutils
bsdutils
busybox-initramfs
busybox-static
bzip2
ca-certificates
cdparanoia
cdrdao
cmap-adobe-japan1
command-not-found
command-not-found-data
console-setup
console-terminus
consolekit
coreutils
cpio
cpp
cpp-4.5
cron
cryptsetup
cups
cups-bsd
cups-client
cups-common
cups-driver-gutenprint
cups-ppdc
dash
dbus
dbus-x11
dc
debconf
debconf-i18n
debianutils
defoma
dictionaries-common
diffutils
dmidecode
dmsetup
dnsmasq-base
dnsutils
docbook-xml
docbook-xsl
dolphin
dosfstools
dpkg
dragonplayer
dvd+rw-tools
e2fslibs
e2fsprogs
ed
eject
exiv2
file
findutils
fontconfig
fontconfig-config
foo2zjs
foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
foomatic-db-engine
foomatic-filters
freespacenotifier
friendly-recovery
ftp
fuse-utils
gcc-4.5-base
gconf2
gconf2-common
gdb
gdebi-core
gdebi-kde
genisoimage
geoip-database
gettext-base
ghostscript
ghostscript-cups
ghostscript-x
gir1.2-glib-2.0
glib-networking
gnupg
gnupg-agent
gnupg2
gpgsm
gpgv
grep
groff-base
growisofs
grub-common
grub-gfxpayload-lists
grub-pc
gs-cjk-resource
gsfonts
gstreamer0.10-alsa
gstreamer0.10-packagekit
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
gstreamer0.10-x
gtk2-engines-oxygen
gwenview
gzip
hdparm
hicolor-icon-theme
hostname
hpijs
hplip
hplip-cups
hplip-data
hunspell-en-ca
hunspell-en-us
ibus-qt4
icoutils
ifupdown
im-switch
info
initramfs-tools
initramfs-tools-bin
initscripts
inputattach
insserv
install-info
intel-gpu-tools
iproute
iptables
iputils-arping
iputils-ping
iputils-tracepath
irqbalance
isc-dhcp-client
isc-dhcp-common
iso-codes
jockey-common
jockey-kde
k3b
k3b-data
kaddressbook
kamera
kate
kbd
kcalc
kde-config-gtk
kde-config-touchpad
kde-window-manager
kde-zeroconf
kdebase-bin
kdebase-data
kdebase-runtime
kdebase-runtime-data
kdebase-workspace
kdebase-workspace-bin
kdebase-workspace-data
kdebase-workspace-kgreet-plugins
kdegames-card-data
kdegraphics-libs-data
kdegraphics-strigi-plugins
kdelibs-bin
kdelibs5-data
kdelibs5-plugins
kdemultimedia-kio-plugins
kdenetwork-filesharing
kdepasswd
kdepim-groupware
kdepim-kresources
kdepim-runtime
kdepim-strigi-plugins
kdepim-wizards
kdepimlibs-kio-plugins
kdesudo
kdm
kdoctools
kerneloops-daemon
keyboard-configuration
kfind
khelpcenter4
kinfocenter
klibc-utils
klipper
kmag
kmail
kmix
kmousetool
knm-runtime
knotes
konsole
kontact
kopete
kopete-message-indicator
korganizer
kpackagekit
kpat
kppp
krdc
krfb
krosspython
ksnapshot
ksysguard
ksysguardd
ksystemlog
ktimetracker
ktorrent
ktorrent-data
kubuntu-debug-installer
kubuntu-default-settings
kubuntu-desktop
kubuntu-docs
kubuntu-firefox-installer
kubuntu-konqueror-shortcuts
kubuntu-netbook-default-settings
kubuntu-notification-helper
kvkbd
kwalletmanager
language-pack-en
language-pack-en-base
language-pack-kde-en
language-pack-kde-en-base
language-selector-common
language-selector-kde
language-support-en
language-support-writing-en
laptop-detect
less
lftp
libaa1
libacl1
libakonadi-contact4
libakonadi-kabc4
libakonadi-kcal4
libakonadi-kde4
libakonadi-kmime4
libakonadiprotocolinternals1
libao-common
libao4
libapparmor-perl
libapparmor1
libarchive1
libasound2
libasound2-plugins
libaspell15
libasyncns0
libatasmart4
libatk1.0-0
libatk1.0-data
libatm1
libattica0
libattr1
libaudio2
libavahi-client3
libavahi-common-data
libavahi-common3
libavahi-core7
libavc1394-0
libbind9-60
libblkid1
libbluedevil1
libbluetooth3
libboost-program-options1.42.0
libbrlapi0.5
libbsd0
libbz2-1.0
libc-bin
libc6
libcaca0
libcairo2
libcanberra0
libcap-ng0
libcap2
libcdparanoia0
libck-connector0
libcln6
libcloog-ppl0
libclucene0ldbl
libcolamd2.7.1
libcomerr2
libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl
libcups2
libcupscgi1
libcupsdriver1
libcupsimage2
libcupsmime1
libcupsppdc1
libcurl3-gnutls
libdaemon0
libdatrie1
libdb4.8
libdbus-1-3
libdbus-glib-1-2
libdbusmenu-glib3
libdbusmenu-gtk3
libdbusmenu-qt2
libdebconf-kde0
libdevmapper-event1.02.1
libdevmapper1.02.1
libdigest-sha1-perl
libdiscid0
libdjvulibre-text
libdjvulibre21
libdmtx0a
libdns69
libdrm-intel1
libdrm-nouveau1a
libdrm-radeon1
libdrm2
libdv4
libedit2
libelf1
libelfg0
libenchant1c2a
libepub0
libexif12
libexiv2-10
libexpat1
libffi5
libfile-basedir-perl
libfile-copy-recursive-perl
libfile-desktopentry-perl
libfile-mimeinfo-perl
libflac++6
libflac8
libfont-afm-perl
libfontconfig1
libfontenc1
libfreetype6
libfribidi0
libfs6
libfuse2
libgadu3
libgcc1
libgconf2-4
libgcrypt11
libgdbm3
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
libgeoip1
libgif4
libgirepository-1.0-1
libgl1-mesa-dri
libgl1-mesa-glx
libglib2.0-0
libglu1-mesa
libgmp3c2
libgmpxx4ldbl
libgnome-keyring0
libgnutls26
libgomp1
libgpg-error0
libgpgme++2
libgpgme11
libgphoto2-2
libgphoto2-port0
libgpm2
libgpod-common
libgpod4
libgps19
libgraphite3
libgs9
libgs9-common
libgssapi-krb5-2
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
libgstreamer0.10-0
libgtk2.0-0
libgtk2.0-bin
libgtk2.0-common
libgudev-1.0-0
libgutenprint2
libhpmud0
libhtml-format-perl
libhtml-parser-perl
libhtml-tagset-perl
libhtml-tree-perl
libhunspell-1.2-0
libhyphen0
libibus-qt1
libical0
libice6
libicu44
libidl0
libidn11
libiec61883-0
libieee1284-3
libijs-0.35
libilmbase6
libimobiledevice2
libindicate-qt1
libindicate5
libiodbc2
libisc62
libisccc60
libisccfg62
libiw30
libjack-jackd2-0
libjasper1
libjbig2dec0
libjpeg62
libjs-jquery
libk3b6
libk5crypto3
libkabc4
libkatepartinterfaces4
libkblog4
libkcal4
libkcalcore4
libkcalutils4
libkcddb4
libkcmutils4
libkdcraw9
libkde3support4
libkdecorations4
libkdecore5
libkdegames5
libkdepim4
libkdesu5
libkdeui5
libkdewebkit5
libkdnssd4
libkemoticons4
libkephal4a
libkexiv2-9
libkeyutils1
libkfile4
libkholidays4
libkhtml5
libkidletime4
libkimap4
libkimproxy4
libkio5
libkipi8
libkjsapi4
libkjsembed4
libkldap4
libkleo4
libklibc
libkmediaplayer4
libkmime4
libknewstuff2-4
libknewstuff3-4
libknotifyconfig4
libkntlm4
libkonq5-templates
libkonq5a
libkontactinterface4
libkopete4
libkparts4
libkpgp4
libkpimidentities4
libkpimtextedit4
libkpimutils4
libkprintutils4
libkpty4
libkrb5-3
libkrb5support0
libkresources4
libkrosscore4
libksba8
libkscreensaver5
libksgrd4
libksieve4
libksignalplotter4
libktexteditor4
libktnef4
libktorrent-l10n
libktorrent2
libkunitconversion4
libkutils4
libkwineffects1a
libkworkspace4
libkxmlrpcclient4
liblastfm0
liblcms1
libldap-2.4-2
liblocale-gettext-perl
liblockfile1
libloudmouth1-0
libltdl7
liblvm2app2.2
liblwres60
liblzma2
libmagic1
libmailtools-perl
libmailtransport4
libmeanwhile1
libmessagecore4
libmessagelist4
libmicroblog4
libmimelib4
libmng1
libmpc2
libmpcdec6
libmpfr4
libmsn0.3
libmtdev1
libmtp8
libmusicbrainz3-6
libmysqlclient16
libmythes-1.2-0
libncurses5
libncursesw5
libneon27-gnutls
libnepomuk4
libnepomukquery4a
libnepomukutils4
libnewt0.52
libnfnetlink0
libnih-dbus1
libnih1
libnl1
libnm-glib-vpn1
libnm-glib2
libnm-util1
libnspr4
libnss-mdns
libnss3
libntfs-3g79
libntfs10
libntrack-qt4-1
libntrack0
libogg0
libokularcore1
libopenexr6
libopenobex1
liborbit2
liborc-0.4-0
libotr2
libpackagekit-glib2-14
libpackagekit-qt14
libpam-ck-connector
libpam-modules
libpam-modules-bin
libpam-runtime
libpam0g
libpango1.0-0
libpaper-utils
libpaper1
libparted0debian1
libpcap0.8
libpci3
libpciaccess0
libpcre3
libpcsclite1
libperl5.10
libphonon4
libpipeline1
libpixman-1-0
libplasma-geolocation-interface4
libplasma3
libplasmaclock4b
libplasmagenericshell4
libplist1
libplymouth2
libpng12-0
libpolkit-agent-1-0
libpolkit-backend-1-0
libpolkit-gobject-1-0
libpolkit-qt-1-1
libpoppler-qt4-3
libpoppler13
libpopt0
libpowerdevilcore0
libppl-c2
libppl7
libprocesscore4b
libprocessui4a
libproxy0
libpth20
libpulse-browse0
libpulse-mainloop-glib0
libpulse0
libpython2.7
libqalculate5
libqapt-runtime
libqapt1
libqca2
libqca2-plugin-ossl
libqgpgme1
libqimageblitz4
libqjson0
libqt4-dbus
libqt4-declarative
libqt4-designer
libqt4-help
libqt4-network
libqt4-opengl
libqt4-qt3support
libqt4-script
libqt4-scripttools
libqt4-sql
libqt4-sql-mysql
libqt4-sql-sqlite
libqt4-svg
libqt4-test
libqt4-xml
libqt4-xmlpatterns
libqtassistantclient4
libqtcore4
libqtgui4
libqtscript4-core
libqtscript4-gui
libqtscript4-network
libqtscript4-sql
libqtscript4-uitools
libqtscript4-xml
libqtwebkit4
libraptor1
librasqal2
libraw1394-11
librdf0
libreadline5
libreadline6
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-emailmerge
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-kde
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-style-oxygen
libreoffice-writer
librpc-xml-perl
libsamplerate0
libsane
libsane-hpaio
libsasl2-2
libsasl2-modules
libselinux1
libsensors4
libsepol1
libsgutils2-2
libshout3
libslang2
libslp1
libsm6
libsmbclient
libsndfile1
libsnmp-base
libsnmp15
libsolid4
libsolidcontrol4a
libsolidcontrolifaces4a
libsoprano4
libsoup-gnome2.4-1
libsoup2.4-1
libspectre1
libspeex1
libspeexdsp1
libsqlite3-0
libss2
libssh-4
libssl0.9.8
libstdc++6
libstlport4.6ldbl
libstreamanalyzer0
libstreams0
libsyndication4
libsysfs2
libtag-extras1
libtag1-vanilla
libtag1c2a
libtalloc2
libtaskmanager4b
libtasn1-3
libtdb1
libterm-readkey-perl
libtext-charwidth-perl
libtext-iconv-perl
libtext-wrapi18n-perl
libtextcat-data
libtextcat0
libthai-data
libthai0
libtheora0
libthreadweaver4
libtiff4
libtimedate-perl
libudev0
libupower-glib1
liburi-perl
libusb-0.1-4
libusb-1.0-0
libusbmuxd1
libutempter0
libutouch-evemu1
libutouch-frame1
libutouch-grail1
libuuid1
libv4l-0
libvirtodbc0
libvisual-0.4-0
libvisual-0.4-plugins
libvncserver0
libvorbis0a
libvorbisenc2
libvorbisfile3
libwavpack1
libwbclient0
libweather-ion6
libwpd-0.9-9
libwpg-0.2-2
libwps-0.2-2
libwrap0
libwww-perl
libx11-6
libx11-data
libx11-xcb1
libx86-1
libxapian22
libxau6
libxaw7
libxcb-atom1
libxcb-aux0
libxcb-dri2-0
libxcb-render0
libxcb-shape0
libxcb-shm0
libxcb1
libxcomposite1
libxcursor1
libxdamage1
libxdmcp6
libxext6
libxfixes3
libxfont1
libxft2
libxi6
libxinerama1
libxkbfile1
libxml-parser-perl
libxml2
libxml2-utils
libxmu6
libxmuu1
libxp6
libxpm4
libxrandr2
libxrender1
libxslt1.1
libxss1
libxt6
libxtst6
libxv1
libxvmc1
libxxf86dga1
libxxf86vm1
libzip1
linux-firmware
linux-generic
linux-headers-2.6.38-8
linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-sound-base
locales
lockfile-progs
login
logrotate
lp-solve
lsb-base
lsb-release
lshw
lsof
ltrace
makedev
man-db
manpages
mawk
memtest86+
mime-support
min12xxw
mlocate
mobile-broadband-provider-info
modemmanager
module-init-tools
mount
mountall
mscompress
mtools
mtr-tiny
multiarch-support
myspell-en-au
myspell-en-gb
myspell-en-za
mysql-client-core-5.1
mysql-common
mysql-server-core-5.1
nano
ncurses-base
ncurses-bin
nepomukcontroller
net-tools
netbase
netcat-openbsd
network-manager
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-pptp-kde
ntfs-3g
ntfsprogs
ntpdate
ntrack-module-libnl-0
nvidia-common
obex-data-server
obexd-client
odbcinst
odbcinst1debian2
okular
okular-extra-backends
openprinting-ppds
openssh-client
openssl
os-prober
oxygen-cursor-theme
oxygen-icon-theme
oxygen-icon-theme-complete
packagekit
packagekit-backend-aptcc
parted
partitionmanager
passwd
pciutils
pcmciautils
perl
perl-base
perl-modules
phonon
phonon-backend-gstreamer
pinentry-qt4
plasma-dataengines-addons
plasma-dataengines-workspace
plasma-desktop
plasma-netbook
plasma-scriptengine-declarative
plasma-scriptengine-javascript
plasma-scriptengine-python
plasma-widget-facebook
plasma-widget-folderview
plasma-widget-kimpanel
plasma-widget-kimpanel-backend-ibus
plasma-widget-menubar
plasma-widget-message-indicator
plasma-widget-networkmanagement
plasma-widget-quickaccess
plasma-widgets-addons
plasma-widgets-workspace
plymouth
plymouth-label
plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
pm-utils
pnm2ppa
policykit-1
policykit-desktop-privileges
polkit-kde-1
poppler-utils
popularity-contest
powermgmt-base
ppp
pppconfig
pppoeconf
pptp-linux
printer-applet
procps
psmisc
pulseaudio
pulseaudio-esound-compat
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-module-x11
pulseaudio-utils
pxljr
python
python-apport
python-apt
python-apt-common
python-cairo
python-central
python-chardet
python-crypto
python-cups
python-cupshelpers
python-dbus
python-debian
python-gdbm
python-gnupginterface
python-gobject
python-gobject-cairo
python-httplib2
python-imaging
python-kde4
python-keyring
python-launchpadlib
python-lazr.restfulclient
python-lazr.uri
python-minimal
python-oauth
python-packagekit
python-pexpect
python-pkg-resources
python-problem-report
python-pycurl
python-pyudev
python-qt4
python-qt4-dbus
python-simplejson
python-sip
python-smbc
python-software-properties
python-support
python-uno
python-wadllib
python-wsgi-intercept
python-xapian
python-xdg
python-xkit
python-zope.interface
python2.7
python2.7-minimal
qapt-batch
quassel
quassel-data
radeontool
rdesktop
readline-common
rekonq
rfkill
rsync
rsyslog
rtkit
samba-common
samba-common-bin
sane-utils
sed
sensible-utils
sgml-base
sgml-data
shared-desktop-ontologies
shared-mime-info
smbclient
software-properties-kde
soprano-daemon
splix
ssl-cert
strace
sudo
syslinux
syslinux-common
system-config-printer-common
system-config-printer-kde
system-config-printer-udev
systemsettings
sysv-rc
sysvinit-utils
tar
tcl
tcl8.4
tcpd
tcpdump
telnet
time
toshset
ttf-dejavu-core
ttf-freefont
ttf-indic-fonts-core
ttf-kacst-one
ttf-khmeros-core
ttf-lao
ttf-liberation
ttf-opensymbol
ttf-punjabi-fonts
ttf-takao-pgothic
ttf-thai-tlwg
ttf-ubuntu-font-family
ttf-unfonts-core
ttf-wqy-microhei
tzdata
ubuntu-extras-keyring
ubuntu-keyring
ubuntu-minimal
ubuntu-standard
ucf
udev
udisks
ufw
unattended-upgrades
uno-libs3
unzip
update-inetd
update-manager-core
update-manager-kde
upower
upstart
ure
ureadahead
usb-creator-common
usb-creator-kde
usb-modeswitch
usb-modeswitch-data
usbmuxd
usbutils
userconfig
util-linux
uuid-runtime
vbetool
vim-common
vim-tiny
virtuoso-minimal
virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin
virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
wamerican
wbritish
wget
whiptail
wireless-crda
wireless-tools
wodim
wpasupplicant
x-ttcidfont-conf
x11-apps
x11-common
x11-session-utils
x11-utils
x11-xfs-utils
x11-xkb-utils
x11-xserver-utils
xauth
xbitmaps
xcursor-themes
xdg-user-dirs
xdg-utils
xfonts-base
xfonts-encodings
xfonts-mathml
xfonts-scalable
xfonts-utils
xinit
xinput
xkb-data
xml-core
xorg
xorg-docs-core
xserver-common
xserver-xorg
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-input-all
xserver-xorg-input-evdev
xserver-xorg-input-mouse
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
xserver-xorg-input-wacom
xserver-xorg-video-all
xserver-xorg-video-apm
xserver-xorg-video-ark
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-chips
xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
xserver-xorg-video-geode
xserver-xorg-video-i128
xserver-xorg-video-i740
xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-mach64
xserver-xorg-video-mga
xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
xserver-xorg-video-qxl
xserver-xorg-video-r128
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-rendition
xserver-xorg-video-s3
xserver-xorg-video-s3virge
xserver-xorg-video-savage
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
xserver-xorg-video-sis
xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
xserver-xorg-video-trident
xserver-xorg-video-tseng
xserver-xorg-video-vesa
xserver-xorg-video-vmware
xserver-xorg-video-voodoo
xterm
xz-utils
zip
zlib1g
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right package list for a desktop installation? I don't think `virtuoso-*` should be included. Could you check your `/var/log/apt/history.log` for new packages?

Comment: Yes - definitely - CD install not the DVD install.  history.log showed two packages.  Maybe these are included in the default install for people who want to install into VirtualBox or its open-source equivalent.

Comment: Perhaps I need to find out which packages are installed in a minimal environment and the extra packages installed by [..what?..] (tasksel?)

Comment: I did a new install using the Alternate CD and used this answer as reference for installing additional packages. I also found out that the `virtuoso-*` packages are a database thing.