# How to get a list of preinstalled packages?

Tags: installation, package-management

And I'd like to get this list **directly** and if possible from an external source (maybe repositories?).

Almost all one-liners I have found didn't work for me. So I hope there is an indicator somewhere that denotes packages as "preinstalled".

PS: I don't want to run a clean installation in a VM.

Comment: Would you mind fetching the contents from a Live CD directly?

Comment: I found the list mikewhatever posted on the CD too but, you know, I don't always have a CD ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Every *buntu release has a .manifest or .list file that lists preinstalled packages. This file is located [online](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).

For example:

- Lubuntu 20.04.1 64bit ➜
  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04/release/lubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest
- Ubuntu 14.04.5 32bit ➜
  http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386.manifest
- Ubuntu 12.04.5 32bit ➜
  http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.manifest

...and so on.

Comment: I've compared the Kubuntu CD contents with a [fresh installation inside VBox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38497/what-packages-are-installed-on-a-fresh-installation/41246#41246), and it seems that the contents match a Live CD, not an actual installation (e.g. the installer, ubiquity, is included in Mike's list)

Comment: That's probably true. The ubiquity, ntfsprogs and unused locales are removed at the end of the installation.

Comment: Does the manifest list includes dependent packages as well? For example, `libgomp1` is not listed in the manifest file but is a dependent of `libgcc-5-dev`, which is on the manifest file.