# A complete list of pre-installed applications/packages?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'm currently working on a (mandatory) stripped version of Ubuntu 12.04LTS GNOME on my Chromebook. My question is, is there any way to get a list of all the normal applications on a clean install? Not packages like "libhtml-tagset-perl 3.20-2", which is for behind-the-scenes terminal utilities, but rather things like "Eye of Gnome" or "RhythmBox". Actual applications that you would normally see in the dash. If that's too much to ask or is simply unavailable, I understand. Thank you for your time!
                                                           -Andrew

Comment: Look in `/usr/share/applications/`. Is that any good for you?

Comment: @Alaa That would be so on a full install. But on a stripped image, the list is only the ones that came preinstalled with it. Therefore, no image viewer, video player, etc. I would need to have a list of those applications on a full install, not the one I'm currently running. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of preinstalled packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50077/how-to-get-a-list-of-preinstalled-packages)

Answer (score 2):

`apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop` will print out all the direct dependencies of the ubuntu-desktop package, without including all the behind the scenes libraries. This should give a fairly good reflection of a typical desktop installation. Is that what you had in mind?