# List of Ubuntu Versions with Corresponding Linux Kernel Version

Tags: kernel, versions

Is there a list of Ubuntu versions with default corresponding Linux kernel versions somewhere?

I would specifically like to know the most recent version of Ubuntu that still used Linux Kernel 2.x.

Comment: I landed here looking for kernel versions in point releases, which wasn't in the answers below. This link was helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support  It gives major and point releases, their kernel version and support schedule, for fairly modern releases.  I didn't add as answer because it doesn't really help cross-referencing kernel 2.x, as OP wanted, but it might help others like me that land here just looking for kernel versions in point releases.

Comment: @WilburWhateley Your link doesn't work any more, but see my answer.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

| Ubuntu version | Code name | Linux kernel version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24.04 | Noble Numbat | 6.6 |
| 23.10 | Mantic Minotaur | 6.5 |
| 23.04 | Lunar Lobster | 6.2 |
| 22.10 | Kinetic Kudu | 5.19 |
| 22.04 | Jammy Jellyfish | 5.15 |
| 21.10 | Impish Indri | 5.13 |
| 21.04 | Hirsute Hippo | 5.11 |
| 20.10 | Groovy Gorilla | 5.8 |
| 20.04 | Focal Fossa | 5.4 |
| 19.10 | Eoan Ermine | 5.3 |
| 19.04 | Disco Dingo | 5.0 |
| 18.10 | Cosmic Cuttlefish | 4.18 |
| 18.04 | Bionic Beaver | 4.15 |
| 17.10 | Artful Aardvark | 4.13 |
| 17.04 | Zesty Zapus | 4.10 |
| 16.10 | Yakkety Yak | 4.8 |
| 16.04 | Xenial Xerus | 4.4 |
| 15.10 | Wily Werewolf | 4.2 |
| 15.04 | Vivid Vervet | 3.19 |
| 14.10 | Utopic Unicorn | 3.16 |
| 14.04 | Trusty Tahr | 3.13 |
| 13.10 | Saucy Salamander | 3.11 |
| 13.04 | Raring Ringtail | 3.8 |
| 12.10 | Quantal Quetzal | 3.5 |
| 12.04 | Precise Pangolin | 3.2+ |
| 11.10 | Oneiric Ocelot | 3.0 |
| 11.04 | Natty Narwhal | 2.6.38 |
| 10.10 | Maverick Meerkat | 2.6.35 |
| 10.04 | Lucid Lynx | 2.6.32 |
| 09.10 | Karmic Koala | 2.6.31 |
| 09.04 | Jaunty Jackalope | 2.6.28 |
| 08.10 | Intrepid Ibex | 2.6.27 |
| 08.04 | Hardy Heron | 2.6.24 |
| 07.10 | Gutsy Gibbon | 2.6.22 |
| 07.04 | Feisty Fawn | 2.6.20 |
| 06.10 | Edgy Eft | 2.6.17 |
| 06.06 | Dapper Drake | 2.6.15 |
| 05.10 | Breezy Badger | 2.6.12 |
| 05.04 | Hoary Hedgehog | 2.6.10 |
| 04.10 | Warty Warthog | 2.6.8 |

Comment: How was this list obtained?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions is a source. Sylvain and me posted this at the same time  so we decided to keep both but I was not going to make it an exact copy of the other one by also including the source ;-)

Comment: How did Wiki editors come up with that list? Answer from reference links: random websites like Phoronix. How did those random websites find that out? OK, enough for me. I only trust ubuntu.com ;-) https://askubuntu.com/a/1117872/52975

Comment: That's a wrong list, ex.: Linux computer 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:43:35 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 55):

You can get the list of the Ubuntu versions and their corresponding kernels [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions):

```
4.10    Warty Warthog       2.6.8
5.04    Hoary Hedgehog      2.6.10
5.10    Breezy Badger       2.6.12
6.06    Dapper Drake        2.6.15
6.10    Edgy Eft            2.6.17
7.04    Feisty Fawn         2.6.20
7.10    Gutsy Gibbon        2.6.22
8.04    Hardy Heron         2.6.24
8.10    Intrepid Ibex       2.6.27
9.04    Jaunty Jackalope    2.6.28
9.10    Karmic Koala        2.6.31
10.04   Lucid Lynx          2.6.32
10.10   Maverick Meerkat    2.6.35
11.04   Natty Narwhal       2.6.38
11.10   Oneiric Ocelot      3.0
12.04   Precise Pangolin    3.2 or newer
12.10   Quantal Quetzal     3.5
13.04   Raring Ringtail     3.8
13.10   Saucy Salamander    3.11
14.04   Trusty Tahr         3.13 or newer
14.10   Utopic Unicorn      3.16
15.04   Vivid Vervet        3.19
15.10   Wily Werewolf       4.2
16.04   Xenial Xerus        4.4 or newer
16.10   Yakkety Yak         4.8
17.04   Zesty Zapus         4.10
17.10   Artful Aardvark     4.13
18.04   Bionic Beaver       4.15 or newer
18.10   Cosmic Cuttlefish   4.18
19.04   Disco Dingo         5.0
19.10   Eoan Ermine         5.3
20.04   Focal Fossa         5.4 
20.10   Groovy Gorilla      5.8
21.04   Hirsute Hippo       5.11 
21.10   Impish Indri        5.14
22.04   Jammy Jellyfish     5.15
22.10   Kinetic Kudu        5.19
23.04   Lunar Lobster       6.2
23.10   Mantic Minotaur     6.5
24.04   Noble Numbat        6.6
```

Comment: Thank you for including the "or newer" comments.  It seem there is not always a 1:1 correlation between Ubuntu version and Linux kernel major version.  I recently obtained a Trusty Tahr ISO via ubuntu.com and installed it into a VM.  The kernel version was 4.2.  I believe this corresponds to the "trusty linux-lts-wily" table at http://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html and this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/linux-image-generic-lts-wily  At the same time I have a laptop with Trusty Tahr whose kernel version is  3.19 (still receiving updates).

Comment: @PeterFord Thanks, this page lists all the kernels that LTS releases will get (or already have): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Wikipedia link made it very clear that I could update my 14.04.4 LTS to kernel version 4.2.0-nn.

Comment: Link and list. Good

Comment: @SylvainPineau freshy updated :=D

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for keeping the list up to date - I appreciate your devotion

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [this version table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions) or [this directory listing](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). I think that is what you are interested in.

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

**Image manifest**

You can see which packages are pre-installed as mentioned at: [How to get a list of preinstalled packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50077/how-to-get-a-list-of-preinstalled-packages)

E.g., on Ubuntu 18.04, the packages are at: http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest

Then, since I know that my kernel is located at: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic, to find the package name I did:

```
apt-file search /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
```

which gave:

```
linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
```

So I just search for `linux-image-` in the `.manifest` and it gives:

```
linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic   4.15.0-29.31
```

so I conclude that Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Linux kernel 4.15.

**packages.ubuntu.com**

If you search for the package name on Google: `linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic`, it also leads us to the packages.ubuntu.com page: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic

Then, on the breadcrumb navigation in that page, there is a link to the "kernels" section: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kernel/

And by searching for `linux-image-` in that page, we find *several* kernels that can be installed in the system.

Answer (score 5):

The Ubuntu release cycle page keeps an up-to-date [graph](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle) of the recent releases:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For all this info except the kernel version you can just read the CSV provided by [`distro-info-data`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=distro-info-data) package:

```
$ column -t -s, /usr/share/distro-info/ubuntu.csv | tail

17.10      Artful Aardvark    artful    2017-04-13  2017-10-19  2018-07-19
18.04 LTS  Bionic Beaver      bionic    2017-10-19  2018-04-26  2023-04-26  2023-04-26  2028-04-26
18.10      Cosmic Cuttlefish  cosmic    2018-04-26  2018-10-18  2019-07-18
19.04      Disco Dingo        disco     2018-10-18  2019-04-18  2020-01-23
19.10      Eoan Ermine        eoan      2019-04-18  2019-10-17  2020-07-17
20.04 LTS  Focal Fossa        focal     2019-10-17  2020-04-23  2025-04-23  2025-04-23  2030-04-23
20.10      Groovy Gorilla     groovy    2020-04-23  2020-10-22  2021-07-22
21.04      Hirsute Hippo      hirsute   2020-10-22  2021-04-22  2022-01-20
21.10      Impish Indri       impish    2021-04-22  2021-10-14  2022-07-14
22.04 LTS  Jammy Jellyfish    jammy     2021-10-14  2022-04-21  2027-04-21  2027-04-21  2032-04-21
```

Also available for `debian.csv`.

Probably with a `curl`/`awk` magic you could generate the kernel column from https://packages.ubuntu.com/-series-/kernel/ bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the exact version number of a release by looking at the `linux-image-generic` package. E.g. for lunar:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/linux-image-generic

which currently lists 6.2.0.20.20. It also has a link to the changelog, which shows when the upgrades were released.