# What version of Ubuntu support Power8 micro threading (aka split core)

Tags: kernel

Split-core (micro-threading) support was put in the upstream kernel version 3.15, and dynamic split-core in 4.3. What version of Ubuntu includes this support?

Comment: You basically have 2 options: the LTS (=14.04) or the current version (15.10) See http://askubuntu.com/a/517140/15811 for the kernel numbers. But you can add any new kernel to Ubuntu if you are up to it ;) It might be a bit daunting at 1st but it is also a good experience

Comment: Look into the ubuntu kernel list http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/. 
Kernel 3.15 for Ubuntu 14.10 (utopic)
Kernel 4.3 for Ubuntu 15.10 (wily)