# Ubuntu Installation Partition

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, partitioning

I have two ubuntu versions installed in my system: 12.04 and 14.04. How do I know which partitions (home and root) belong to which version, without depending on size of the partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to check all the partitions for a file called `/etc/os-release`. That file identifies the Linux distribution and version. If you're doing it "by hand," you can use any number of lines. If you want a script to do something with the information, you should probably focus on one line. Here's the file from an Ubuntu 14.04.3 installation:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Once you've found that file, you can check `/etc/fstab` on the same partition for identification of additional partitions associated with the installation. In a default Ubuntu setup, these will identify other partitions by UUID values, which you can obtain from `blkid`, as in:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3: UUID="5028fa50-0079-4c40-b240-abfaf28693ea" TYPE="ext4"
```

If you use LVM, the `/etc/fstab` file will most likely refer to logical volumes by device ID, as in `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-home`. There are other legal formats in `/etc/fstab` that might be used if you edited it manually, too.

Again, doing this by hand will require some digging about, but it can be scripted if you want to build a tool to piece it all together automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the label of the kernel.  Here's an answer that includes a list of all the Ubuntu versions and which kernel they use: https://askubuntu.com/a/517140/366676.

You can easily mount the `/boot/` partition on any modern device.

Comment: Though I didn't quite understand how this figures out the partition, Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you connect the drive to any modmernish machine, you will only be able to mount the `/boot/` partitions, because they are vfat.  They boot partition contains kernel information, and that chart will help you determine what version of Ubuntu each one is.