# Boot failure with Kernel 4.x

Tags: boot, kernel

My HP Workstation Z820 is not booting with Kernel > 3.9x

Trying to update to 15.10 or 16.04 fails.

New install of 16.04 from CD fails also - see image..

[image]

Comment: That's a kernel panic in your picture & 4.2* is from 15.10, not 16.04 [see this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version). I don't know if this gives you a clue but can't tell any more from the info.

Answer (score 1):

Studying the image is above my paygrade. However, the first step is to isolate the cause of the problem.

"Boot failure with Kernel 4.x" implies that your system boots with 2.x or 3.x. However, you write that your workstation also isn't booting with 3.9x. This suggests that your system doesn't boot regardless of the Kernel.

If you want to test this, then try installing a system with 2.x or 3.x again. If these also fail, then the cause probably isn't the kernel.

Possible causes:

- Hardware Failure

Could be USB media/CD-DVD Drive/Memory/CPU. etc...

- Bad Install Media (Check MD5 or SHA Checksum)
- BIOS Setting

Another test is try a non-Linux distribution, something like PC-BSD. If *this* boots, then this suggests that the problem *might* be related to the Linux kernel. If it *doesn't* boot, then this suggests hardware failure.

Comment: OP says cannot boot with kernel '>' ie greater than 3.9*

Comment: I'm sorry. Strike my answer. I missed that. I would encourage the OP to provide as much information as possible. Is he dual booting? What graphics card is he using? Is there anything unusual about his partition or drive setup? Etc...