# What specific mainline kernel does Ubuntu 17.10 ship with?

Tags: kernel, 17.10

and where can i look in the future to determine what mainline kernel Ubuntu is applying patches to and shipping?

Comment: The artful kernel is **linux kernel series 4.13**

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version

Comment: unfortunately it just says 4.13 but what i really need to know is 4.13.2 or 4.13.3, etc.

Comment: @Craig 4.13 = 4.13.0

Answer (score 2):

I HIGHLY suggest you read the release notes, lots of changes.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes

> **Linux kernel 4.13**
>
> Ubuntu 17.10 is based on the Linux release series 4.13. It includes
>   support for the new IBM z14 mainframe CPACF instructions and new KVM
>   features.

If you need details, check the changelog or launchpad pages

changelog - http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_4.13.0.16.17/changelog

launchpad - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-team

Package search - https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/artful/linux-meta

> linux-headers-4.13.0-16 Header files related to **Linux kernel version**
>   **4.13.0**