# Error when setting up compat wireless 2.6

Tags: kernel, make, compat-wireless

The code I used was `make load` but it brought to me this error.

```
compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2.6-master/config.mk:204: 
"WARNING: CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT will be deactivated or not working   
because kernel was compiled with CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=n. 
Tools using wext interface like iwconfig will not work.   
To activate it build your kernel e.g. with CONFIG_LIBIPW=m."  
make: *** No rule to make target 'load' stop.
```

Comment: compat-wireless has been superceded. I strongly suspect there is a better, newer driver for your device. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/download

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  The 2.6 kernel was used last in 2011, and any system using it should no longer be used on networks today  (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version for a list of kernel versions and releases; are you really using something that old???)