# Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, 24.04 Too much problems with do not detected bluetooth, wifi, sound card, bright buttons, touch screen, pen, camera

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, hp

Ubuntu HP Specter x360 14-eu0174ng inkl. USB-C Hub & Pen 14" 2.8k OLED Touch 120Hz, Intel Ultra 7-155Hx22, 32GB RAM, 1TB SSD. With Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 and 24.04 do not detected bluetooth, wifi, sound card, bright buttoms, touch screen, pen, camera, etc. Please, I need help!

Comment: Hopefully, by the official release of Ubuntu 24.04 on April 25, 2024, my computer will function correctly. I have worked comfortably with Ubuntu for over 15 years, and it's the first time a computer fails to detect much of the hardware. I understand this may be due to the novelty of the machine, but I have full trust in Ubuntu.

Comment: I downloaded an ISO from here: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-iot. And I can install directly from the USB. However, we continue to face issues with Bluetooth, WiFi, sound card, brightness buttons, touch screen, pen, camera not working. Also, there is no ISO file available for the Intel 15th generation with 22 cores. Does anyone know if these issues will be fixed in version 24.04? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507317/edit) and add additional information in your question. Comments are our channel to ask you for information and provide guidance.

Comment: Don't use IOT images. Use the desktop ISO to install for laptop/desktop use.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I noticed that you use [Iot](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-iot) image on laptop product, I recommended using [Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)/[Server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) image to make bootable usb drives to install ubuntu on your laptop device.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your message and your thoughtful recommendation. I truly appreciate your suggestion regarding the use of a Desktop/Server image for creating bootable USB drives to install Ubuntu on my laptop devices. However, it appears that this option does not work for my computer, as the installation process halts at "hid-generic 001F:8087:0AC, hidraw7: Sensor hub hid..."

Comment: It usually takes 20-30 minutes to complete the installation process, I assumed you use "ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso" from Ubuntu official website, use "Make startup disk" application(it's an application of Ubuntu) to make a bootable usb drive, select "erase disk and install ubuntu" option during partitioning page, if there's something different than yours, feel free to ask. If system halts again, maybe 22.04.4 kernel isn't compatible for hp spectre laptop.

Comment: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version) is ubuntu kernel version list and [OS installation instruction](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview).

Comment: I would like to apologize for any previous confusion and ensure that you understand the gravity of the situation. I have followed all the suggestions you provided; however, the issue persists. My device still lacks essential functionalities such as sound card, Bluetooth, touchscreen, wifi, bright buttons, etc.

I greatly appreciate your efforts to assist me thus far, but it seems that the problem lies at a deeper level than the usual troubleshooting steps. I am concerned that there may be a more serious issue with the hardware of my device.