kernel message question
We currently are facing obstacle in OS installation for Linux Ubuntu on C3000 Refresh platform specific for C3558R & C3758R
The newer version has no trouble on OS installation. However, the older version seems unable to even initiate the installation.
Please help advise is there any way, we can resolve this installation issue?
Here is the distribution and kernal version that’ve been tested.

Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop-amd64 (kernal 6.8.0-45) intalled ok
Ubuntu 22.04 live server amd64 (kernal 5.11 ) fail
Ubuntu 22.10 live server amd64 (kernal 5.13) fail
Ububtu 23.10 live server amd64 (kernal 6.5.0-14) fail
Ubuntu 22.04 destop-amd64 (kernal6.8.0-31) fail
Ubuntu 23.04 destop amd64 (kernal 6.2.0-20) fail

Currently, when running on ubuntu 23.10, kernel 6.5.0-14, "ACPI FPDT: Duplicate resume performance record found." will always be output.
Ubuntu 24.04, kernel 6.8.0-45 does not have this problem,
Is there any information that can explain this difference?
(Update) We also tried Ubuntu 22.04 destop-amd64 (kernel6.8.0-31) but got the same error message "ACPI FPDT: Duplicate resume performance record found.", Is there any information to correct the above errors between kernel 6.8.0-31 and 6.8.0-45?
Thanks

Your details contain many off-topic and unsupported releases, as well as errors. You can refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version for a list of kernel versions (22.04 had 5.15; so 22.10 released six months later had a newer kernel being 5.18). Media exists with LTS releases using different kernels (eg. 22.04 media exists with 5.15, 5.18, 6.2, 6.5 & 6.5 kernels where an ISO using HWE is used). Your details contain errors & off-topic details with no clear question; you do mention one unstated systems works, so use that!

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

The 6.8 kernel found on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS gets security & other fixes; the 6.5 kernel is EOL & unsupported in Ubuntu, as releases that used it are either EOL, or where it was used on a supported kernel (via HWE) they upgraded to 6.8 when EOL was reached.  By the very nature of unsupported, updates & fixes aren't made for those systems.

the message "ACPI FPDT: Duplicate resume performance record found" is one of several that have started being generated by Linux Kernels recently (i'm guessing 6.x series). for your message, you can see it (as a patch to the source) here:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-acpi/patch/20191230094601.16008-1-rui.zhang@intel.com/
i've recently had a similar ACPI message, "ACPI Warning: Time parameter 255 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware" turning up in the dmesg logs on a number of netbook-style machines i manage, with the message repeating every 10 seconds or so ad infinitum.
as far as i can tell, the code to generate these messages is being added by the Kernel Developers to try and 'send a message' to BIOS authors telling them that there are deviations from the ACPI specifications in their BIOS code. generally the causes of these messages are non-fatal/minor deviation from the ACPI specifications that has no impact on the running of the affected machine.
the down side:

you can not suppress these messages without building your own version of the Linux Kernel,
the 'spam' being generated in the dmesg logs are so extreme that other, important messages, are lost. the log files that dmesg reads are of finite size, and so continuous spamming from the Kernel will eventually displace everything else.

the solution: you need to contact the Linux Kernel Developers, and politely ask them to remove the generation of these messages (or provide a way of suppressing them), pointing out that the repeated - every 10 seconds or so - messages constitute spam and are affecting the usability of the Linux Kernel. good luck with that - i have tried!
