# GUI tool for formating to exFAT

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, exfat, disk-formatting

I just formated a partition to exFAT using the terminal command `sudo mkfs.exfat -n`. Is it possible to do the same thing using a GUI?

Before people comment that the Terminal command works just fine (which it indeed does), I want to say that I am introducing a friend to Ubuntu. He's in his 70's and very unsavvy. People like him usually get scared by any mention of the terminal. I like reccomending Ubuntu to people who know very little about computers, and such people don't like to use the terminal. I don't like telling them that in order to do this or that they have to open the terminal and put together this and that command. They are used to simpler things.

Comment: Have you tried GNOME Disks? Or GParted?

Comment: @smile4ever GParted doesn't seem to have any option for formating to exFAT, as far as I can see, even after installing the packages. The option is greyed out. Will try GNOME Disks.

Comment: This seems to work for people using gparted http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=12121.msg98331;PHPSESSID=g0fcr00folfett6v9ejfe4qee0#msg98331

Comment: @bistoco There is only partial support for exFAT in GParted in Ubuntu and this partial support does not include formatting a partition as exFAT.

Comment: Kepp in mind it's very difficult to resize/extend exFAT. See: [Shrink exFAT partition](https://superuser.com/questions/393132/shrink-exfat-partition/1349305)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First of all you need to install `exfat` support packages. You can do it by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

Then you will be able to use `gnome-disks` to format exfat.

1. Open "Disks" application in Dash.
2. Select your disk drive.

[image]

3. Press the "gears" button and select "Format".
4. Select "Custom" as "Type" and type in "exfat" as a filesystem.

[image]

5. Press "Format".

Comment: Before doing the terminal command mentioned in OP, I had to install two packages.  Is that the case for this GUI method you mention,  also? If so,  maybe it's worth adding that to the answer,  for the sake of future readers.

Comment: You need to install the packages before you do it. I will add that.

Comment: The GUI changed a bit when I tested in 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771668/why-is-it-that-i-am-unable-to-format-my-pendrive-in-exfat-using-gparted/1089839#1089839

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件, booting my Ubuntu 18.04 x64 boot stick, `dpkg -l exfat-utils` shows me, that `exfat-utils V. 1.2.8` is already installed. Looks like this became a standard package?

Comment: @FrankNocke yes, I would expect it to be pre-installed, since that is the case for `gnome-disks` which I mention in my answer, and `gnome-disks` supports exfat and is preinstalled. This explains how to see the preinstalled packages: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50077/how-to-get-a-list-of-preinstalled-packages but I can't find it at: http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest not sure why.

Comment: Kernel 5.4 supports exFat so i'd recommend not to install other tools for such a sensitive task, upgrade if possible!

Answer (score 2):

**Kde Partition Manager** is another alternative to gnome-disks *(which I don't have a good experience with when it comes to formatting)*.

It's Like GParted but (still) have support for exFAT.

I just made a more detailed post about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006553/143133).

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Note

*If you're introducing this to a new user, make sure to tell them to use the correct (USB) disk on the right.*