ExFAT option not found in KDE partition manager
I am on Kubuntu 24.04 LTS. I want to switch an HDD from NTFS to ExFAT. Using KDE partition manager I deleted the partitions and then in the create new partition menu, there is no option for ExFat.
I googled and found linux has builtin support for ExFAT. What do I do now?

The linked question is about gparted but the missing exfatprogs might apply to KDE partition manager as well: see https://askubuntu.com/a/999581/1186757
