# How to create an "unformatted" partition in Gnome Disks

Tags: partitioning

Gnome Disks makes users select "Custom" sometimes and type in what partition they want. If I do this to try to create an unformatted partition it says "Unknown" afterwards and also produces an error dialog.

What is the method to create an unformatted partition using Gnome disks?

Comment: Well, the resulting partition created this way (entering an invalid type) is unformatted... You either have to ignore the error message or use a different tool, like GParted instead of Disks.

Comment: I need to create an exfat partition, so I had to abandon GParted (unfortunately). Further, GParted only allows MiB sizes whereas Disks uses MB sizes. So I would rather create the unformatted partition using Disks since I HAVE to use Disks to create the exfat. Do you know of a "formal" way to create an unformatted partition using Gnome Disks?

Comment: Why do you want to create an unformatted partition first and then format it to exfat later? Just do both at once, as described e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/750687/367990).

Comment: The reason is because I am formatting a flash drive and having extra (unformatted) space allows for the health (and speed) of the drive, especially when TRIM is not operational.